# Examples of the preposition "of" in the sense "characterized or identified by"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

In [The American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=of), I saw a definition (One sense) of preposition "of"-which mean "characterized or identified by". Could someone explain me it through example?

Comment: is not "A year of famine." an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example: "She had hair of golden hue,"  uses the preposition to characterize the color of her hair.

Comment: In this sense 'of' is used in the preposition phrase act a adjective, am i right?

Comment: Almost. My example might equally be  expressed as, "She had  golden hair." In this form, "golden" is the adjective. In my first example, the entire phrase "of golden hue" functions as an adjectival phrase. The preposition itself isn't an adjective.

Comment: My first example is slightly literary. Simply  adding the word "a" makes the sentence quite ordinary: "She had hair of a golden hue."